# YUI compressor 2.48 windows path error

Tags: java, yui, yui-compressor

I am using YUI compressor to compress js file, but while passing the full path on Windows7 it is giving error

```
java -jar c:\yui\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar c:\js\CCOM.js -o c:\js\CCOMA.js
```

gives Error as follows

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: yuiCCOMA.js:\yui\CCOM.js (The filena
me, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

the jar and source file do exist and it works fine when I run it directly from source directory

Comment: Looks like the compressor always expects the input file to be the final argument. Try `java -jar c:\yui\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -o c:\js\CCOMA.js c:\js\CCOM.js'

Comment: Hmmm, looking at the examples, your format looks ok. You could also try enclosing your fielnames in quotes or using forward-slashes as path separators, rather than backslashes

Comment: @barnyr I tried all possibilities, nothing worked.. then I downloaded 2.4.7 and that worked as expected.. not sure if this is known bug for 2.4.8

Comment: very useful to know, thanks for updating

Comment: This is a known bug for 2.4.8 see https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/111 and https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/78.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a bug in Version 2.4.8:

https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/111

https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/78

Until that is fixed, you can use 2.4.7 from here: https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/downloads

Comment: Yes, the latest v2.4.8 still not fixed yet. v2.4.7 is fine for using.